# Namespace inheritance

Tags: c++, namespaces

First of all I cannot understand why i get this error

```
error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
```

For the following code

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a {

    void print() {
            std:cout << "a" << std::endl;
    }           
}       

namespace b {
    using namespace a;

    void print() {
            std:cout << "b" << std::endl;
    }           
}

int main() {

    b::print();

}
```

Broadly speaking I'm investigating the behavior of inheritance in namespaces since I don't need classes per se (they would just be singletons anyway). Any advice or gotchas to look out for with the namespaces approach?

---

Edit:
Okay I;m sorry about the typo. In that case can i extend the question?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a {


    void print2() {
            print();
    }

    void print() {
            std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
    }           
}       

namespace b {
    using namespace a;

    void print() {
            std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
    }           
}

int main() {

    b::print2();

}
```

This doesn't compile 
     error: ‘print’ was not declared in this scope

Is there a way i can emulate class inheritance in a generic way?

For example if a and b were classes, a would be printed. If print was declared as virtual then b would be printed.

Is any of this possible or is namespace "inheritance" just a cheap hack?

---

Edit 2:

Declaring print before print2 outputs a. I guess my question now is: 
is there a way or emulate the virtual keyword in this situation? So that the following would print b and c respectively.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace a {

    void print() {
            std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
    }

    void print2() {
            print();
    }

}       

namespace b {
    using namespace a;

    void print() {
            std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
    }
}

namespace c {

    using namespace a;

    void print() {
            std::cout << "c" << std::endl;
    }
 }

int main() {

    b::print2();
    c::print2();

}
```

Comment: `std::cout` - note two colons.

Comment: `std:` is a label for `goto`. The statement following the label is `cout << << "a" << std::endl;`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a typo.

Comment: There's no such thing as namespace inheritance. If you need inheritance/polymorphism, use classes.

Comment: You should ask a question at a time, not modify your question to ask something different each time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry this isn't a standard SO question you can Google, copy & paste an answer and get some points.

If you follow the code I'm sure you can see what I'm trying to do: I need inheritance but not multiple objects, it feels dumb to create a class if all the methods will be static anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spell `std::cout` wrong (`std:cout`).

In your code `std:` declares a label for `goto`. And the rest of the statement is:

```
cout << "a" << std::endl;
```

Hence, the compiler complains on unknown identifier `cout`.

**Update:**

After you fixed the typo, change the order of functions to:

```
void print() {
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
}           

void print2() {
        print();
}
```

**Update 2:**

After you edited the question again it completely lost its initial meaning. But the answer is `No`. No, you cannot inherit namespaces.

Comment: I'm probably not thinking about this whole object oriented thing properly. Thanks for your time.